# How to pull a parameter into a string in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ERROR: 
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')' ...endMail?email_to=#{'appointment.email'}
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end ...check+the+website+for+details').read ... ^
I want to pull a parameter into a string in Rails.

```
require 'open-uri'
response = open('http://mqttxy.mybluemix.net/sendMail?email_to=# 
{'@appointment.email'}&from=abc@gmail.com&subject=New+Appointment&message
=Please+check+the+website+for+details').read
```

Comment: Can you please provide example, error message, and a full description of your problem so we can provide solutions? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using double quotes for string interpolation like this:

```
require 'open-uri'
response = open("http://mqttxy.mybluemix.net/sendMail?email_to=# 
{'@appointment.email'}&from=abc@gmail.com&subject=New+Appointment&message
=Please+check+the+website+for+details").read
```